# Removing first and follow set intersections for LL(1)

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, ll-grammar

I'm currently working on a compiler construction for a project and I'm at the point in which I'm making my grammar LL(1) compliant.

I've managed to replace the EBNF notation just fine, removed left recursions and did some factoring, but I seem to be stuck on a production rule having an intersection between first and follow set, causing ambiguity.
Terminals are within single quotes, and multIndice, idnest_ and params are not relevant to the problem. 
The production for multIdnest ends up having an intersection of 'id' for first and follow sets and I am having a hard time getting rid of it.

Any help on how to move forward would be greatly appreciated, not necessarily just to fix my problem but in general how to go about this kind of situation.

```
factor       -> multIdnest 'id' postCall | 'int' | 'float'
variable     -> multIdnest 'id' multIndice
functionCall -> multIdnest 'id' '(' params ')'
multIdnest   -> idnest multIdnest | EPSILON
idnest       -> 'id' idnest_
```

Comment: Maybe it would help if you provided your original  grammar so we can see what you are trying to achieve. What is `idnest_` supposed to be, for example? Also, why don't you just use an LALR parser generator?

Comment: Right, of course, here is the complete EBNF grammar https://pastebin.com/E6dxAapa . The reason I am going for LL(1) is simply because that is part of the instructions I have been given for the project. I am aware there is also an intersection of first and follow for multVarDecl but I figured I should be able to apply the same principle I learn from this situation

Comment: If you think of `.` as beginning a variable qualification, rather than ending one, then it is no different from the conversion of infix expressions. The problem will be distinguishing a `variable` from a `functionCall` in the context of an assignment statement. That can be done, too, I think but it's a pain. None of this would be an issue eith an LR grammar. I suppose this is a school assignment so you have no room to argue about the design decision.